# Why does a query to the REST API return only one FeedItem at a time?

Tags: soql, rest-api

My query is:

```
SELECT Id,ParentId,Type,CreatedById,CreatedDate,IsDeleted,LastModifiedDate,
SystemModstamp,CommentCount,LikeCount,Title,Body,LinkUrl,RelatedRecordId,ContentData,
ContentFileName,ContentDescription,ContentType,ContentSize,InsertedById 
FROM FeedItem
```

It returns all the results, but only one per page, resulting in as many API calls as there are FeedItems! None of the other objects I'm querying seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ContentData is a blob field, queries that contain blob fields are returned one row at a time to control the overall response payload size. remove that field from the query, and only query it when you need to separately.

Answer (score 1):

In the query there is field named contentData which is base64 encoded string for file content.  The salesforce rest api response size limit must have causing the issue.  Try removing contendata from query and check.